# How to trim libraries in jar file?

Tags: java, jar, compilation, libraries, shared

Suppose I have 3 jar files (libraries) that use the same `commons.jar` library. This common library is redundant in all 3 jar files.

The commons.jar file weighs in at 20MB.

Each dependent jar weighs in around 40 MB.

So overall we have 40+40+40 = 120 MB (out of which 60 MB is the same commons.jar)

I was wondering if there is a way to use a single commons.jar and allow others to use that single instance instead of each jar having its own copy?

Comment: Jar files **generally** don't contain their dependencies, unless they shade/shadow/fatjar them, which is the exception rather than the norm. In other words: in most build systems the commons library will only exist once, even if it's a transitive dependency of three of your dependencies. What build system/configuration do you use?

Comment: I'm using Maven to build the jar files. So you're saying they don't contain their dependencies and that if I were to build the jar files, the 40 MB would be solely that library's own code and NOT the commons.jar?

Comment: I think it would help to get specific. Actually there's no such thing as `commons.jar` but there *are* a lot of `commons-x.jar` libraries. A Maven shade *will* pack all dependencies into one jar, but only *once* so if you have more than one jar with commons-x.jar included as a dependency in it, it suggests that jar could have been shaded individually.

Comment: @SyedMominNaqvi: yes, that is the default behaviour of Maven and the most common one. The other approach (where a jar file contains all its dependencies) is a bit more rare, but does exist. It goes under various names (uber jar, fatjar, jar